# building opencv dependent ros packages from source?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get `ros-kinetic-desktop` onto Ubuntu 16.04 - ARM. However, I would like to [build opencv library 3.1.0 with cuda support](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d15/tutorial_building_tegra_cuda.html) and use it for ROS applications instead of the custom ros package `opencv3`. Looking at the reverse dependencies on `ros-kinetic-opencv3`, I am assuming that I need to build the packages `rqt-image-view` and `cv-bridge` from source and link them with the new opencv that I am building. However, I am clueless of how to do this. Could someone please confirm if the above mentioned two packages are the only ones required to be built and I would appreciate if you could also guide me through the procedure of how it is to be done. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258614/building-opencv-dependent-ros-packages-from-source?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

why you want to use the Version 3.1.0 at the moment opencv3 package of ROS use 3.2.0.
Therefore when you compile 3.2.0 with cuda support a build of rqt-image-view and cv-bridge
should not be necessary or I'm wrong with this idea? Take a look on the opencv3 package side.

---

Originally posted by [Mondi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22211/mondi/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-04-06**:
Oh. You mean that instead of building two packages that depend on opencv, I could just fetch the source code for `opencv3` and add Cuda support while building it. That makes sense but I'm not sure if it works. I'll probably give it a try. But if anyone who is sure can confirm it, that'd be assuring